# Getting values from filtered excel table

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I am currently trying to copy all filtered values from one excel sheet to another. But it doesnt copy all visible/filtered values. Here a screenshot from my table (the other table where I paste my values is empty):
[image]

For example: When I filter the column "Ordnernummer" for the value "1/3" it copies only the following values:
[image]

This is how it should look like:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Sub getCellRangeValues()

    'declare Variant array to hold cell range values
    Dim myValuesArray() As Variant

    'declare Long to hold the last cell with data
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'declare variables to hold loop counters used to iterate through the individual values in the cell range
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim columnCounter As Long

    With Worksheets("Konfiguration") 'worksheet with the data

    'get the last row from column a
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'get values from all filtered rows and assign them to an array
    myValuesArray = .Range("C2:I" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GoLabel").Activate
    'loop through each value in array (rows)
    For rowCounter = LBound(myValuesArray, 1) To UBound(myValuesArray, 1)

        'loop through each value in array (columns)
        For columnCounter = LBound(myValuesArray, 2) To UBound(myValuesArray, 2)
            Call setData(myValuesArray, rowCounter, columnCounter)
        Next columnCounter

    Next rowCounter
End Sub
```

```
Sub setData(myValuesArray() As Variant, rowCounter As Long, columnCounter As Long)
    With Worksheets("GoLabel")
    .Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = myValuesArray(rowCounter, columnCounter)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So you filter to *show* `1/3` and it copies `1/1`?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I added the wrong pics. It should copy all values from 1/3, but it only copied the first 2. Its the same case when I filter for other values from a different column.

Comment: When you set the filter manually: Is it filtering all your data? Often, it stop when it finds an empty row

Comment: The filter works perfectly fine when I use it manually. It even shows them as intended. VBA just doesnt safe all the values.

Comment: Add a line break on `End With` and run your code, check what values are assigned to your array. If they are the values you expect then step through your loop line by line to see where it's going wrong - otherwise if the array is missing expected data you'll need to revise how you assign your array.

Comment: @SamuelEverson I debugged the array and added a line break and indeed the data is already missing in the array. But I cant figure out why the assignment isnt working as intended.

Comment: With the same line break, try `?Range("C2:I" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address` (not sure if that syntax will work tho)

Comment: You can't use .Value with a multi-area range: you will only get the first area.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Instead of saving the values in an array I just simply copy the values and paste them in my new sheet. Here the corresponding code:

```
    'worksheet with the data
    With Worksheets("Konfiguration")

    'get the desired column range which is declared in the cell
    startRange = "C1"
    endRange = "I101"

    'select values from all filtered rows
    .Range(startRange & ":" & endRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    End With

    'worksheet which I fill with the copied data
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GoLabel").Activate

    With Worksheets("GoLabel")
        .Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```